# How to use the fine_tune_checkpoint in TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to load a fine_tune_checkpoint to start the training with.
I added the appropriate field in the config file, and set the value to be a checkpoint I have from a model previously trained from scratch.
The way tfod saves checkpoints is by using 3 files with different postfixes (data, index, meta) and I set the value to be the name of the checkpoint without the postfix.

`fine_tune_checkpoint: "/path/to/my/checkpoint/dir/model.ckpt-190000"`

There's no indication whatsoever that what I'm doing is either right or wrong. No logs stating the checkpoint is loaded and no errors, warnings or indications that it is not.

How can I tell if the checkpoint was actually loaded?

I'm happy for any suggestions to verify it either way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might be useful https://gilberttanner.com/blog/creating-your-own-objectdetector

Answer (score -1):

you need to do two things to solve this:

1- give absolute path to this parameter like this:

> fine_tune_checkpoint:"c:/user/desktop/path/to/my/checkpoint/dir/model.ckpt-190000"

2- the fine tune should be in the same folder of the previous folder you train these steps
**"model.ckpt-190000"** other ways the model will start from step 0 .

regards.